# get key value that is an object in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components

apex method is returning a Map<sobject,List> i want to use the key value fields in js controller -
my js code looks like this -

```
@wire(getSubmittedQuestions,{userId:userId}) 
wiredSubmittedQuestions({error,data}){ 
if(data){ 
for(let key in data){ 
this.wrapperSubmitted = data[key]; 

//i am not able to get Name when i do this 
let titleVarSubmitted = key.Name ; 
}
```

Debugging key shows the values returned , it looks like this -
[va_Security__c (Id:aD*******, Name:Test Account, va_Status__c:Save)]

Answer (score 1):

For Demo
Apex Code:

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static Map<String,String> getMap(){
        Map<String,String> dummyMap = new Map<String,String>();
        dummyMap.put('A','a');
        dummyMap.put('B','b');
        dummyMap.put('C','c');
        return dummyMap;
    }
```

On JS Side

```
getMap()
.then(data=>{
    for (var key in data) {
         console.log('key', key);
         console.log('value', data[key]);
       }
     })
     .catch(error=>{
        console.log('error ',JSON.stringify(error));
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of
for(let key in data){}
use :

1. data.foreach(element => console.log(element.Name))

exemple your apex return you a map =
{"va_Security__c" => {Name: "Test Account",va_Status__c:"Save"}}

**In your JS**

let titleVarSubmitted;

if(data){

data.forEach(element => titleVarSubmitted = element.Name  );

console.log('title',titleVarSubmitted); // should display the name

}

2. for (const [key, value] of data) {
   console.log(key, value);
   }

If you want to know more on map() in javascript , use this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/map